# Designer could not be started because of a permissions issue

Tags: visual-studio, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

My first delve into the world of Universal apps seems to have come to a grinding halt about 2 minutes in, as I am unable to access even the designer.

This hasn't occurred before and all my other projects (non-UWP apps) work fine, the designers work fine in those projects, but for some reason in this UWP project, the XAML Designer cannot be loaded due to what appears to be some pretty extensive permission issues.

I have Google'd these errors and nothing I find I am able to do, despite being the only Administrator (and indeed the only user) on this not networked computer, I am unable to change permissions to the Reference Assemblies folder (which is what was recommended online).

I have posted the full list of errors below in the hopes someone knows what is going on, and what I can do to fix this so I can get on with some work :(

I was prompted to change permissions when this popped up, but the CMD window that opened said it had successfully changed them, clearly not!

```
System.Security.SecurityException
Designer could not be started because of a permissions issue on the drive to which it is installed. Please check the permissions of the folder before trying to start the designer.
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, FrameworkName targetFramework, String identifier, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExpressionHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.<StartTask>b__6()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Open the Settings and check if developer mode not active

Answer (score 0):

For me, when opening a .xaml file, a message popped up asking if I wanted to elevate permissions to the folder.  Clicking OK brought up a black command window, which didn't appear to be doing anything for a couple minutes.  Just leaving it alone it ultimately dismissed itself and the designer loaded successfully.